# How to convert this LINQ query syntax that connects two objects to method syntax?

Tags: c#, linq

How to do this in method syntax form:

```
foreach (var o in from o in orders
                  from oi in o.OrderItems
                  where oi.ProductName == "Widgets"
                  select o.OrderID)
    Console.WriteLine("{0}", o);
```

tried this but not working:

```
foreach (var o in orders
    .SelectMany(o => o.OrderItems, (o, oi) => new {<<idk what to put here>> })
    .Where(oi => oi.ProductName == "Widget"))
{
    Console.WriteLine("WIDGET: {0}", o.OrderID);
}
```

Finally I used this code and it worked!

```
foreach (var o in orders
    .SelectMany(o => o.OrderItems, (o, oi) => new { o.OrderID, oi.ProductName })
    .Where(oi => oi.ProductName == "Widgets"))
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0}", o.OrderID);
}
```

Comment: You have query syntax and you want to convert it into linq syntax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the solution to your problem. 
You should be using something like this :

```
foreach (var item in orders.SelectMany(x => x.OrderItems).Where(y => y.ProductName == "Widgets"))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0}", item.OrderId);
            }
```

I have created a working sample to your problem : [Click Here](http://rextester.com/VZLHW56567)

Hope this solves your problem. Thanks!!

Comment: this is what I wanted. though in the "item.OrderId" in the foreach body, i can't find the OrderId property. It connected to the child object instead of the parent object. I only see the properties of the OrderItems. :(

Comment: I made some few changes and phew it worked finally!

orders.SelectMany(o => o.OrderItems, (o, oi) => new {o.OrderID, oi.ProductName }).Where(oi => oi.ProductName == "Widgets")

Comment: Nice, or you can do something like this :
`foreach (var item in orders.SelectMany(x => x.OrderItems).Where(y => y.ProductName == "Widgets").Select(z=>z.OrderId))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0}", item);
            }`

Comment: well I don't need the select part at the end anymore since it's already working and I need to have the simplest code as possible. thank you btw

Answer (score 4):

Method syntax will be like that:

```
orders.Where(o=>o.OrderItems.Any(oi=>oi.ProductName == "Widgets")).Select(o=>o.OrderID)
```

Comment: how about when using select many? see the one I tried but not working.